# Dynamic styling for pseudo element's content in Vue2.x

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that is basically an Icon and a tooltip; it shows the tooltip( whose text comes from the parent component as a prop) on mouse hover. I implemented the tooltip with the help of pseudo-elements so I need to update the pseudo element's content with the prop's value. I am also aware of the fact that Pseudo element rules of CSS aren’t part of the DOM, and therefore they can’t be altered using JavaScript methods, but I found a bunch of workarounds that basically work for any CSS property but not `content`(I can see they work (e.g. for width property of tooltip or its color ) but strangely not for the `content` property), here is what I have done so far, any help would be appreciated:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- <style>
            :root {
            --info-msg: {{tooltipContent}};
            }
        </style> -->
        <div class="infoBar">
            <svg-icon
                fill="#d5d5dc"
                :width="16"
                :height="16"
                name="common/c-info"
                class="infoBar__icon"
            />
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ContentInfo',
  props: {
    tooltipContent: {
      type: String,
      default: 'hint text goes here'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.tooltipContent)
    this.applyCSS()
  },

  beforeUpdate () {
    this.applyCSS()
  },
  methods: {
    applyCSS () {
      const cssRule = `
      .infoBar:after{
        content: ${this.tooltipContent};
      }`
      const style = document.createElement('style')
      style.type = 'text/css'
      this.$el.appendChild(style)
      style.innerHTML = cssRule
    }
  }

}
</script>

<style lang="postcss" >

  .infoBar{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 24px;
    &::after {
      background-color: #000;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      width: 198px;
      height: 40px;
     /*content: var(--info-msg)*/
      display: none;
      padding: 11px 26px 10px 27px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 80%;
      transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 10px));
      z-index: 999;
    }
    &::before {
      background-color: #000;
      content: '';
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 6px;
      z-index: 999;
      top: 0;
      left: 80%;
      transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 10px)) rotate(45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      display: block;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      display: block;
    }
    &__icon:hover{
        fill: #e4002b;
      }
  }

  </style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

follow these steps and you can use props in the css as css variables:

1. use props in a computed to return an object of css variables and bind this object to the style of the component
2. you should give the component a class name as the css variables can be accessed from within the class name in the css style section
3. as for css variables that should be in the string format to work correctly you should use `JSON.stringify()` (this is the case for the `content` css property)

run the example bellow and see for yourself, both color and text of the `after` element showing by hover are coming as a prop from the parent component:

```js
Vue.component('pseudo', {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Hover me',
    }
  },
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cssVars() {
      return {
        '--color': this.color,
        '--text': JSON.stringify(this.text),
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<div class="content" :style="cssVars">{{title}}</div>`,
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.content {
  color: red;
}

.content:hover::after {
  content: var(--text);
  color: var(--color);
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pseudo color="green" text="I'm from Prop!!"></pseudo>
</div>
```